# JS function stopwatch application confuses the user

Tags: javascript

I wrote a javascript application but I end up with a total confusion. This js application needs to run in minutes, seconds, and hundredths of seconds. The part about this mess is when the stopwatch show, in this case 03:196:03. Here is my confusion. When the stopwatch shows 196, is it showing hundredth of seconds? Does anybody can check my function and tell me what part needs to be corrected in case that the function is wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>my example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            //Stopwatch
    var time = 0;
    var started;
    var run = 0;
    function startWatch() {
        if (run == 0) {
            run = 1;
            timeIncrement();
            document.getElementById("countDown").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("resetCountDown").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Stop";
        } else {
            run = 0;
            document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Resume";
        }
    }//End function startWatch
    function watchReset() {
        run = 0;
        time = 0;
        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Start";
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
        document.getElementById("countDown").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("resetCountDown").disabled = false;
    }//End function watchReset
    function timeIncrement() {
        if (run == 1) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                time++;
                var min = Math.floor(time/10/60);
                var sec = Math.floor(time/10);
                var tenth = time % 10;

                if (min < 10) {
                    min = "0" + min;
                }
                if (sec <10) {
                    sec = "0" + sec;
                } else if (sec>59) {
                    var sec;
                }
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec + ":0" + tenth;
                timeIncrement();
            },10);
        }
    } // end function timeIncrem
    function formatNumber(n){
        return n > 9 ? "" + n: "0" + n;
    }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
    <p id="output"></p>
    <div id="controls">
        <button type="button" id ="start" onclick="startWatch();">Start</button>
        <button type="button" id ="reset" onclick="watchReset();">Reset</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about trying to post this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  I just learned today that it's for questions like this.

Comment: @3abqari This question is about changing the functionality of code which does not belong at code review. Code Review is for cleaning up code, so that it does *the same thing* in a better way.

Comment: You probably need `sec -= 60*min` or some modulus operation.

Comment: Have you tried boiling your code down to the [minimum required to reproduce this effect](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This would make it easier to answer your question and you might even find the answer yourself during the process.

Comment: A question about user confusion seems like it belongs on https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally weird!

First you're using `document.getElementById()` for non-existing elements: maybe they belong to your original code and your didn't posted it complete.

Then I don't understand your time-count method:

- you make `timeIncrement()` to be launched every 10 ms: so `time/10` gives you a number of milliseconds
- but you compute `min` and `sec` as if it was a number of seconds!

From there, all is wrong...

Anyway IMO your could make all that simpler using the `getMilliseconds()` function of the `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = [
  Math.floor(time/100/60 % 60),
  Math.floor(time/100 % 60),
  time % 100
].map(formatNumber).join(':')
```

```js
var time = 0;
var started;
var run = 0;
function startWatch() {
  if (run == 0) {
    run = 1;
    timeIncrement();
  } else {
    run = 0;
  }
}
function watchReset() {
  run = 0;
  time = 0;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
}
function timeIncrement() {
  if (run == 1) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      time++;
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = [
        Math.floor(time/100/60 % 60),
        Math.floor(time/100 % 60),
        time % 100
      ].map(formatNumber).join(':')
      timeIncrement();
    },10);
  }
}
function formatNumber(n){
  return (n < 10 ? "0" : "") + n;
}
startWatch()
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```